# Java overloading toString() method when array of class is given

Tags: java, arrays, object, overriding, tostring

This is how you overload the `toString()` method:

```
public class Person extends Object {
    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().serializeNulls().create();
        return (gson.toJson(this));
    }
}
```

In this example I get a JSON string when calling the `toString()` method of `Person` instead of the default string representation of an `Object`.

But what if I have an array of `Person` like:

```
Person[] persons = new Person[3];
System.out.println(persons.toString());
```

What do I have to do or which method(s) do I have to override in that case?

Comment: It is not possible, but you can use Arrays.toString(Object[] a); which will call the toString() method on each object in the array.

Comment: Why downvoting and requesting to close this question? I mean yes, there is another similar one but I could not find it because there are many ways to ask this question. Thanks for your help, I will use `Arrays.toString(Object[] a)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot override default array's `toString`. If you want to convert an array of objects into the string, use `Arrays.toString()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override the "array" version as their is no array version.  What really happens is that the Array has a toString method which will be called.

If you had used a Java Collection as opposed to an Array, it would print out your `Person#toString` method 3 times as the `Collection#toString` iterates over each object in the collection.

Comment: It will call the Array toString method.

Comment: That's what I said, "What really happens it that the Array has a toString method"

Comment: You are right, but it does not try to call Person#toString.

Comment: Actually this got me curious if it's possible to override the toString() method of an array variable using the reflection/instrumentation API. Probably not.

Comment: I was thinking about java collections, I revised my answer

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override method `toString` on array but you can use `Arrays.toString(Object[])` to print array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to extend Object, it is there by default.

To print the array content you can use:

```
Person[] persons = new Person[3];
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(persons));
```