# Why don't my arrays work?

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

I swear that I put them in right. They should be generating/using a 25 numbers from -100 to 100, and the programs I use compile perfectly fine, but output the following:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: java IntegerArrayRunner
Numbers Array: [I@3343c8b3
Numbers Array Element Count: 25
Numbers Array Sum: 0
Numbers Array Average: 0
Evens Array: [I@272d7a10
Evens Array Element Count: 25
Evens Array Sum: 0
Evens Array Average: 0
Odds Array: [I@1aa8c488
Odds Array Element Count: 25
Odds Array Sum: 0
Odds Array Average: 0
Negatives Array: [I@3dfeca64
Negatives Array Element Count: 25
Negatives Array Sum: 0
Negatives Array Average: 0

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Seriously, what's up with this? Why does it print out those odd combinations of symbols and characters? What do they even mean? Here are the programs used.

```
public class IntegerArrayMain
{      
   private int[] numbers = new int [25];
   private int[] evens = new int [25];
   private int[] odds = new int [25];
   private int[] negatives = new int [25];
   private int sum;
   private int numbersSum;
   private int evenSum;
   private int oddSum;
   private int negaSum;
   private int avg;
   private int numbersAvg;
   private int evenAvg;
   private int oddAvg;
   private int negaAvg;

   DiceClass rng = new DiceClass(200);

   //============================NUMBERS====================================

   /**
   *Generates the 25 numbers.
   */
   public int[] setNumbers()
   {
      for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
      {
         numbers[0] = (rng.getRoll() - 100);
         sum += numbers[i];
      }
      return numbers;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the numbers.
   */
   public int[] getNumbers()
   {
      return numbers;
   }
   /**
   *Finds and returns the sum of the numbers.
   */
   public int setNumsSum()
   {
      int numbersSum = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
         sum += numbers[i];
      }
      return numbersSum;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the numbers' sum.
   */
   public int getNumsSum()
   {
      return numbersSum;
   } 
   /**
   *Finds and returns the average of the numbers.
   */
   public double setNumsAvg()
   {
       double numbersAvg = sum/numbers.length;
       return numbersAvg;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the numbers' average.
   */
   public int getNumsAvg()
   {
      return numbersAvg;
   }  
   //============================EVENS======================================

   /**
   *Locates the even numbers.
   */
   public void findEvens()
   {
      int n = 0;
      for(int i : numbers){
         if((i % 2) == 0){
         evens[n] = i;
         }
         n++;
      }
   }
   /**
   *Returns the even numbers.
   */
   public int[] getEvens()
   {
      return evens;
   }
   /**
   *Finds and returns the sum of the evens.
   */
   public int setEvensSum()
   {
      int evenSum = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < evens.length; i++) {
         sum += evens[i];
      }
      return evenSum;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the even numbers' sum.
   */
   public int getEvensSum()
   {
      return evenSum;
   }  
   /**
   *Finds and returns the average of the evens.
   */
   public double setEvensAvg()
   {
       double evenAvg = sum/evens.length;
       return evenAvg;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the even numbers' average.
   */
   public int getEvensAvg()
   {
      return evenAvg;
   }  

   //============================ODDS=======================================

   /**
   *Locates the odd numbers.
   */
   public void findOdds()
   {
      int n = 0;
      for(int i : numbers){
         if((i % 1) == 0){
         odds[n] = i;
         }
         n++;
      }
   }
   /**
   *Returns the odd numbers.
   */
   public int[] getOdds()
   {
      return odds;
   }
   /**
   *Finds and returns the sum of the odds.
   */
   public int setOddsSum()
   {
      int oddSum = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < odds.length; i++) {
         sum += odds[i];
      }
      return oddSum;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the odd numbers' sum.
   */
   public int getOddsSum()
   {
      return oddSum;
   }  
   /**
   *Finds and returns the average of the odds.
   */
   public double setOddsAvg()
   {
       double oddAvg = sum/odds.length;
       return oddAvg;
   } 
   /**
   *Returns the odd numbers' average.
   */
   public int getOddsAvg()
   {
      return oddAvg;
   }  

   //============================NEGATIVES==================================

   /**
   *Locates the negative numbers.
   */
   public void findNegatives()
   {
      int n = 0;
      for(int i : numbers){
         if((i % 2) == 0){
         negatives[n] = i;
         }
         n++;
      }
   }
   /**
   *Returns the negative numbers.
   */
   public int[] getNegatives()
   {
      return negatives;
   }
   /**
   *Finds and returns the sum of the negatives.
   */
   public int setNegativesSum()
   {
      int negaSum = 0;
      for( int i = 0; i < negatives.length; i++) {
         sum += negatives[i];
      }
      return negaSum;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the negatives numbers' sum.
   */
   public int getNegativesSum()
   {
      return negaSum;
   }  
   /**
   *Finds and returns the average of the negatives.
   */
   public double setNegativesAvg()
   {
       double negaAvg = sum/negatives.length;
       return negaAvg;
   }
   /**
   *Returns the negative numbers' average.
   */
   public int getNegativesAvg()
   {
      return negaAvg;
   }  
}
```

And the other one:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IntegerArrayRunner
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {

      System.out.println("Numbers Array: " + getNumbers());
      System.out.println("Numbers Array Element Count: " + numbers.length());
      System.out.println("Numbers Array Sum: " + getNumsSum());
      System.out.println("Numbers Array Average: " + getNumsAvg());

      System.out.println("Evens Array: " + getEvens());
      System.out.println("Evens Array Element Count: " + evens.length());
      System.out.println("Evens Array Sum: " + getEvensSum());
      System.out.println("Evens Array Average: " + getEvensAvg());

      System.out.println("Odds Array: " + getOdds());
      System.out.println("Odds Array Element Count: " + odds.length());
      System.out.println("Odds Array Sum: " + getOddsSum());
      System.out.println("Odds Array Average: " + getOddsAvg());

      System.out.println("Negatives Array: " + getNegatives());
      System.out.println("Negatives Array Element Count: " + negatives.length());   
      System.out.println("Negatives Array Sum: " + getNegativesSum());
      System.out.println("Negatives Array Average: " + getNegativesAvg());

   }
}
```

Comment: Wheere the objects in your main>?

Answer (score 0):

The weird characters that you are referring to is the memory address of that array.

You need to either iterate through your array to print the content, or simply use `Arrays.toString(array)` to print out contents of the array.

Try this on a separate Java file for practice:

```
int[] a = {3,5,4,31,23};
System.out.println(a);  // Prints [I@15bdc50
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)); // Prints [3, 5, 4, 31, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are printing the Array for example in the first print line:

```
System.out.println("Numbers Array: " + getNumbers());
```

you are printing the array reference in result `"Numbers Array: " + getNumbers()` will call the `ToString()`on `getNumbers()` result that will return the Hashcode of the Instance, you need to instead do a `getNumbers().length` i guess?

Answer (score 0):

You're printing the value of an array object instead of the contents of the array. If you want to print the contents of the array, consider either writing a function to return a formatted string of the contents or alter your print statement to something like this:

Since you use this multiple times, I suggest you write a function to print a formatted string.

You can write `import java.util.Arrays` at the top of your file and use the `Arrays.toString(numbers)` function if you want to, but if you define a function then you can always change how it looks whenever you want to by editing your function.

```
public String arrayToString(int[] array)
{
    String s = "";
    for (int i; i < array.length - 1; i++)
    {
        s += s + ", ";
    }
    //add last element of the array to the string without a comma
    s += "" + array[array.length - 1];

    //if the array is [1, 2, 3, 4]
    //this will return "1, 2, 3, 4"
    return s;
}
```

And then just use the function value to print it:

`System.out.println("Numbers array: " + arrayToString(numbers));`

Answer (score 0):

Those "odd combinations of symbols and characters" are the hashcodes of the objects which are obtained by calling the `hashcode()` method on an object. When you print an object, Java automatically calls the `toString()` method on that object. Now, in some object (e.g. `int`) `toString()` has been overridden to print the actual value ([check the course code for Integer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28%29)). However, in the case of an array, the `toString()` method has not been overridden; so it falls back to what the `Object` class defines and it simply prints the hashcode of an object ([check the source code of `Object`'s `toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Object.java#Object.toString%28%29)).

Answer (score 0):

Your getNumbers(), getEvens(), getOdds(), getNegatives() are supposed to print the array contents?
If so, you should read this: [Java overloading toString() method when array of class is given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970488/java-overloading-tostring-method-when-array-of-class-is-given)

This question appears to be a duplicate.